# Calculate input field after row added when button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that makes automatically 2 calculations:

1. Calculation of numbers of days after the selection of arrived and departed date from two input date field with calendar, result is stored is field (nbjours)
2. Multiplication of 3 fields (nbcheveaux * days* price), result is stored ind field (total)
   There is a button that when we click on it a new row is added. How can i reproduce the same automatic calculations on the news rows added after click ?

1- my add rows function

```
window. addRow = function addRow(btn) {         
var parentRow = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
var table = parentRow.parentNode;
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
 var tdNbC = document.createElement("td");
var tdDateArrive = document.createElement("td");
var tdDateDepart = document.createElement("td");
var tdNbJour = document.createElement("td");
var tdPrix = document.createElement("td");
var tdTotal = document.createElement("td");
var td3 = document.createElement("td");
 var inputDateArrive = document.createElement("input");
 var inputDateDepart = document.createElement("input");
inputDateArrive.type = "text";
inputDateDepart.type = "text";
inputDateArrive.setAttribute("class", "date");
inputDateDepart.setAttribute("class", "date1");
var inputNbrC = document.createElement("input");
var inputNbrJour = document.createElement("input");
var inputPrix = document.createElement("input");
var inputTotal = document.createElement("input");
var inputButton = document.createElement("button");
inputButton.type = "button";
inputButton.innerHTML = "+";
inputButton.onclick = function(){
    addRow(this);  
};
tdNbC.appendChild(inputNbrC);
tdDateArrive.appendChild(inputDateArrive);
tdDateDepart.appendChild(inputDateDepart);
tdNbJour.appendChild(inputNbrJour);
tdPrix.appendChild(inputPrix);
tdTotal.appendChild(inputTotal);
td3.appendChild(inputButton);
 tr.appendChild(tdNbC);
 tr.appendChild(tdDateArrive);
tr.appendChild(tdDateDepart);
tr.appendChild(tdNbJour);
tr.appendChild(tdPrix);
tr.appendChild(tdTotal);
tr.appendChild(td3);
table.appendChild(tr);
$(inputDateDepart).mask("99/99/9999");
$(inputDateArrive).mask("99/99/9999");
}
```

2- function that calculate numbers of days

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.date1').change(function() {
var start = $('.date').datepicker('getDate');
var end   = $('.date1').datepicker('getDate');
if (start<end) {
var days   = (end - start)/1000/60/60/24;
 $('.days').val(days);
 }
 else {
alert ("Depated date must be greater that arrived date!");
$('.date').val("");
$('.date1').val("");
$('.days').val("");
}
}); //end change function
}); //end ready
```

3- Function that operate the multiplication

```
$('.nbrcevaux,.days,.price').keyup(function() {
var nbrcevaux = parseInt($('.nbrcevaux').val());
var days = parseInt($('.days').val());
var prix = parseInt($('.price').val());
$('.total').val(nbrcevaux * days * prix ); 
});
```

4- HTML Table

```
       <table>
        <tr>
        <td class="centrer">Nbr de chevaux</td>
      <td class="centrer">Arrived Date</td>
       <td class="center">Departed Date</td>
       <td class="centrer">Nb/Days</td>
       <td class="centrer">Prix/jr/ cheval/boxe</td>
     <td class="centrer"> Total</td>

 </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="nbrcevaux" class="nbrcevaux"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="datearrive" class ="date"/> </td> 
        <td><input type="text" name="datedepart" class ="date1"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="nbrjours" class ="days"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="prix" class="price" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="total" class="total"  /></td>
          <td><button type="button" onClick ="addRow(this)">+</button>   </td>
     </tr>
```

How can i integrate the functions calculate numbers of days and multiplication in the added new row displyed after click ?

Comment: First, your code is wrong from the start and wouldn't even run. You start with `window. addRow`, instead of `window.addRow` and frankly that's very poor practice (adding a new global function) in the first place.  But, you are creating new `td` elements and configuring them. You just aren't populating them with any data. Do that with `element.textContent = newContent` if the content is not HTML or `element.innerHTML = newContent` if the content is.

Comment: thank you for your remarks but my codes work properly..

Comment: Please don't worry of the amount of codes found in  Add row function. I would like to integrate the calculations functions in add row function so that the new rows added after click work as the first row...

Comment: `window. addRow` (the very first line you posted) will cause a syntax error due to the space character.

Comment: i arranged it..

Answer (score 0):

So, I was bored and tackled your question, by rewriting it because you had quite a bit of superfluous code.

**Your main issue (with the calculations on the added rows) stems from the fact that you were relying on classes to uniquely identify elements, but that won't cut it.** Each new row and element within the row needs to have its own unique id.

I also took the liberty of making sure that there will only ever be one "Add row" button, as you'll see.

This working example has comments inline to help follow what's going on.

```js
$(function() {

  // Declare & initialize module wide variables to store DOM elements:
  var $txtnbrcevaux = $("#nbrcevaux"), $txtDateArrive = $("#dateArrive"), 
      $txtDepart = $("#datedepart"), $txtnbrjours = $("#nbrjours"), $txtPrix = $("#prix"), 
      $txtTotal = $("#total"), $btnAdd = $("#btnAddRow"), $masterRow = $("#master1");
  
  // Unique value that will identify new elements
  var count = 1;
  
  // Establish the date picker fields
  $txtDateArrive.datepicker();
  $txtDepart.datepicker();
  
  // Wire up the button's click event:
  $btnAdd.on("click", function(){ 
      
    // Make a copy of the last row 
    var newTR =  $("tr[id=master" + count + "]").clone(true);
    
    // Update the new row's id to be unique
    newTR[0].id = "master" + (count + 1);
 
    // Loop through the child elements and modify their id's so that they are unique  
    newTR.children().each(function(index){
      if(this.children.length > 0){
        // Wipe out old (copied values)
        this.firstChild.value = "";
        var oldID = this.firstChild.id;
        this.firstChild.id = oldID.substring(0, oldID.length) + (count + 1);

        // Cloning datepickers creates problems because the clones remain bound to the
        // original input element. Here, we'll create a new input element and then 
        // insert it where the current one is, then we'll remove the current one:
        if($(this.firstChild).is(".date, .date1")){
          var newPicker = document.createElement("input");
          newPicker.id = this.firstChild.id;
          newPicker.name = this.firstChild.name;
          newPicker.setAttribute("class", this.firstChild.className.replace(" hasDatepicker", ""));
          newPicker.style.width = "80px";
          
          // Set up the new datepicker:
          $(newPicker).insertAfter(this.firstChild);
          $(this.firstChild).remove();
          $(newPicker).datepicker();
        }
      }
       

    });
  
    // Increment the count so the next row will use the next number for its id's  
    count++;
    
    // Hide the last row's button
    this.style.display = "none";    
  
    // Add the new row to the table
    $("table").append(newTR);  
 
    // Commented due to not having plugin available
    // $(inputDateDepart).mask("99/99/9999");
    // $(inputDateArrive).mask("99/99/9999");
  });

  $('.nbrcevaux, .days, .price').on("keyup", function() { 
    var nbrCevaux = this.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector(".nbrcevaux").value;
    var days = this.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector(".days").value;
    var prix = this.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector(".price").value; 
    
    // Your problem was that you were trying to work with values from
    // classes and not specific elements. Changing the function to expect
    // the data to be passed to it and having it return the answer allow
    // you to control what goes in and where to put what comes out
    this.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector(".total").value = nbrCevaux * days * prix;
  });
  
  $txtDepart.change(function() {
    var start = $txtDateArrive.datepicker('getDate');
    var end   = $txtDepart.datepicker('getDate');
    
    
    if (start < end) {
      var days   = (end - start)/1000/60/60/24;
      $txtnbrjours.val(days);
      
    } else {
      alert ("Depated date must be greater that arrived date!");
      $txtDateArrive.val("");
      $txtDepart.val("");
      $txtnbrjours.val("");
    }
  }); //end change function  
  
}); //end ready
```

```css
/* This is only added to shrink things down so they appear within the space allotted */
input[type=text] {width:80px;}
body {font-size:.5em;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<table>       
  <tr>
    <td class="centrer">Nbr de chevaux</td>
    <td class="centrer">Arrived Date</td>
    <td class="center">Departed Date</td>
    <td class="centrer">Nb/Days</td>
    <td class="centrer">Prix/jr/ cheval/boxe</td>
    <td class="centrer"> Total</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="master1">
    <td><input type="text" id="nbrcevaux" name="nbrcevaux" class="nbrcevaux"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="dateArrive" name="dateArrive" class ="date"></td> 
    <td><input type="text" id="datedepart" name="dateDepart" class ="date1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="nbrjours" name="nbrjours" class ="days"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="prix" name="prix" class="price"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="total" name="total" class="total"></td>
    <td><button type="button" id="btnAddRow">+</button>   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Hello, i was disconnected, thank you so much for your time to help me out, i try to read and to understand yours codes. The codes are not runned properly on the snippet , only the first row works. when i take them out to run in a browser, only table display nothing work after.

Comment: @BaptisteProphete In the snippet above, as I type into the fields and select dates, the total gets automatically calculated. This is done on the `keyup` event, as you requested.

Comment: In the snippet the first row and the second row work properly, in the others rows calendars are not stored in input date field and number of days are not calculated..